# Show that $\frac 1 2 <\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \le 1$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> If $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle, then show that $$\dfrac 1 2 <\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \le 1$$

Trial: $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge 0\\\implies a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca $$ But how I prove $\dfrac 1 2 <\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ . Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the triangle inequalities:$$a^{2}>(b-c)^{2}\\b^{2}>(a-c)^{2}\\c^{2}>(b-a)^{2}$$

We get $$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}>2a^{2}+2b^{2}+2c^{2}-2ab-2bc-2ca$$

Now divide by $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$ to get,$$1>2-2\left(\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\right)\\\rightarrow \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}>\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @A.D $a^2-(b-c)^2=(a+(b-c))(a-(b-c))=(a+b-c)(a+c-b)$ and he is adding the same thing which I have added.So whats the difference in my answer any this answer.

Comment: your answer is perefectly right . I just want to prove something to OP

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: It's true that your answer is right. But here calculation is more simple.

Comment: Ha Ha Ha.... and nothing more @A.D

Comment: nice answer. +1

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu : Your answer is right so I upvoted that but I think I  need to accept this answer so I accept this.

Comment: @A.D Its not about accepting the answer. You had said that you wanted a simpler answer and I dont think this answer is simpler than mine.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu : It's my personal view that I need to accept this answer. It does not mean that your answer is not qualitative. I don't wanna hurt you. Please forgot about this.

Answer (score 3):

We know from triangle inequality

In a triangle the sum of any two sides is greater  than the third side, from which it follows that

$(a+b-c)(a+c-b)+(b+c-a)(b+a-c)+(c+a-b)(c+b-a)>0$

Just expand this to get the inequality

$\Rightarrow a^2-b^2-c^2+2bc+b^2-c^2-a^2+2ac+c^2-a^2-b^2+2ab>0$

$\Rightarrow -a^2-b^2-c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)>0$

Comment: The calculation is huge. Is there any easier way to solve?

Comment: It is not huge ,you only have to multiply the first expression the others will follow by symmetry.

Comment: Well, the answer's already been accepted, yet if I were the OP I'd be *really* interested in knowing why the very first inequality, from which all then follows, is true. I can't see how is this obvious and/or how the OP can accept it just like that but then get annoyed from some simple multiplications...BTW, +1 since this is a nice answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio now I think its ok???

Comment: @DonAntonio : I know that $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle so the inequality is true. I also want a more simple way to solve the problem. But I get no response for that. So, I accept the answer. I appreciate if someone can solve the problem in more simple way.

Comment: Oh, @AbhraAbirKundu :it *already* was ok before :) My doubt was whether the OP was aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: I see, @A.D....yet I think this answer is as simple as one can expect with only pretty basic geometry and algebra to reach the goal. I see you already accepted another question, yet the basic foundation is the very same and the algebra used is, imfho, pretty alike...of course, it's all up to you to accept whatever seems simpler/nicer/more elegant to you.